# Within docker container use curl.h in .cpp file

Tags: c++

I am in the process of transitioning some code from my local machine to an AWS Cloud9 Environment. I was writing the code for a school project that requires the use of Docker. I wrote the code using a terminal ssh connection to a school computer. On that computer, I cloned cURL using the URL  https://github.com/curl/curl.git
The code works perfect on my ssh connection but when I copy the code and cURL directory over I get an error. The error I get is on the "#include <curl/curl.h>" line, the error is "no file or directory found". I have attempted many different ways to get the code and cURL library to my docker including copying the 2 onto my AWS Environment and mounting the docker when it runs, within the docker image running the git clone command for cURL, within the docker image running the scp command, and doing apt-install curl but still run into the same issue.

I have directly copied the file structure from my ssh connection to my AWS or even docker image so that structure is not the issue. I have ensured when copying the cURL directory, I use -r to get the directory and all its contents. My code heavily relies on the use of curl.h and I cannot think of any other ways to get my .cpp file to compile with curl.h, or even just the cURL directory. I also am assuring when I attempt to compile my .cpp file I am using g++ filename.cpp -lcurl

Comment: Your compiler is complaining it cannot find the header files, so point it to the curl headers with the `-Ipath/to/libcurl/headers` flag. Also note that you will need to actually compile curl into a static (.a) or dynamic (.so) library and install it somewhere under your build tree before you can link to it.

Comment: Although to be honest, can't you simply install the development package for curl inside your Docker container? Then you can do away with building curl yourself.